# Connect Atom IDE to container for python development

Tags: python, docker, atom-editor

So, I'm relatively new to Docker and Atom, but I want to achieve what I would consider a complete and proper way to develop in python or possibly any other language.

I got:

- The basic python container from docker hub based on alpine linux
- A bind between the folder on the host and the app folder on the container
- The Atom IDE on the host

I would like:
The full fledged IDE experience (using the IDE on the host side), but using suggestions, autocomplete, debugging, code run based on what is availlable on the container.

I don't know whether this is feasible or not with Atom, but searching around I found that the paid version of vscode can do that, so I would suspect there should be a way to do it with Atom as well.

Comment: Currently, opening atom at the mounded code gives you all the features of the language server, but misses a debugger. For whatever reason, [atom-ide-debugger-python is missing an `attach` option for remote debugging](https://github.com/facebookarchive/nuclide/blob/master/modules/atom-ide-debugger-python/main.js#L167) and [the atom-ide-community project's near-term roadmap doesn't include working on the debugger](https://github.com/atom-ide-community/atom-ide-community.github.io/issues/3#issuecomment-505311213).